Celery graph only returns the first group executed
tl;dr: A chain of groups and tasks executes correctly in Celery, but the result backend only returns the result of the first group. How do I fix this?
Here is my code:
app.task
def add(prev_result, x, y):
    logger.info(f'prev_result={prev_result} x={x} y={y}')
    return x + y

@app.task
def test_graph_workflow():
    g1 = [add.s(None, 1, 1), add.s(None, 2, 2), add.s(None, 3, 3)]
    t1 = add.s(4, 4)
    g2 = [add.s(5, 5), add.s(6, 6), add.s(7, 7)]
    t2 = add.s(8, 8)
    
    res = chain(group(g1), t1, group(g2), t2).apply_async()

    print("res: ", res)

    return res

The results of the graph are rather strange; they print the first three subtasks three times, but no results beyond the first group in the chain.
In [140]: r.graph
Out[140]:
0d504f90-6b66-4abb-a2ea-ece05f261b47(4)
     c757ec9f-8e23-4edf-98fd-a67c923e8caf(3)
          6827e0c4-ea15-4825-b49d-88c4a4eaeb3f(0)
          3d22901e-28b3-48f3-a053-3bfb930a6eff(0)
          1dd91f66-f453-4c44-bdfb-8ac3bba7cdb8(0)
c757ec9f-8e23-4edf-98fd-a67c923e8caf(3)
     6827e0c4-ea15-4825-b49d-88c4a4eaeb3f(0)
     3d22901e-28b3-48f3-a053-3bfb930a6eff(0)
     1dd91f66-f453-4c44-bdfb-8ac3bba7cdb8(0)
6827e0c4-ea15-4825-b49d-88c4a4eaeb3f(0)
3d22901e-28b3-48f3-a053-3bfb930a6eff(0)
1dd91f66-f453-4c44-bdfb-8ac3bba7cdb8(0)

You probably don't need to read it, but it's merely evidence that all tasks executed and got logged correctly.
2024-05-19 05:45:33,657: INFO/MainProcess] Task common.tasks.add[1dd91f66-f453-4c44-bdfb-8ac3bba7cdb8] received
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,657: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task common.tasks.test_graph_workflow[0d504f90-6b66-4abb-a2ea-ece05f261b47] succeeded in 0.24247083299269434s: <AsyncResult: 106cf123-274d-41cc-a9af-a19ef84f23d0>
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,659: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] common.tasks.add[6827e0c4-ea15-4825-b49d-88c4a4eaeb3f]: prev_result=None x=1 y=1
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,660: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task common.tasks.add[6827e0c4-ea15-4825-b49d-88c4a4eaeb3f] succeeded in 0.0011837500060210004s: 2
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,661: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] common.tasks.add[3d22901e-28b3-48f3-a053-3bfb930a6eff]: prev_result=None x=2 y=2
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,662: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task common.tasks.add[3d22901e-28b3-48f3-a053-3bfb930a6eff] succeeded in 0.0010571250022621825s: 4
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,663: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] common.tasks.add[1dd91f66-f453-4c44-bdfb-8ac3bba7cdb8]: prev_result=None x=3 y=3
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,666: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task common.tasks.add[1dd91f66-f453-4c44-bdfb-8ac3bba7cdb8] succeeded in 0.0024847500026226044s: 6
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,666: INFO/MainProcess] Task common.tasks.add[65569c7d-4eef-4c2b-90ec-f4aac9050137] received
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,669: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] common.tasks.add[65569c7d-4eef-4c2b-90ec-f4aac9050137]: prev_result=[2, 4, 6] x=4 y=4
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,671: INFO/MainProcess] Task common.tasks.add[6b583529-28d8-4c03-be5e-987056d52724] received
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,672: INFO/MainProcess] Task common.tasks.add[98c216ed-8e1e-420e-a574-8757e7dd304f] received
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,672: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task common.tasks.add[65569c7d-4eef-4c2b-90ec-f4aac9050137] succeeded in 0.004549792007310316s: 8
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,673: INFO/MainProcess] Task common.tasks.add[68cec14f-acdc-4b10-b64b-5d6418285358] received
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,675: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] common.tasks.add[6b583529-28d8-4c03-be5e-987056d52724]: prev_result=8 x=5 y=5
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,676: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task common.tasks.add[6b583529-28d8-4c03-be5e-987056d52724] succeeded in 0.0013171250029699877s: 10
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,680: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] common.tasks.add[98c216ed-8e1e-420e-a574-8757e7dd304f]: prev_result=8 x=6 y=6
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,688: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task common.tasks.add[98c216ed-8e1e-420e-a574-8757e7dd304f] succeeded in 0.009023334001540206s: 12
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,691: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] common.tasks.add[68cec14f-acdc-4b10-b64b-5d6418285358]: prev_result=8 x=7 y=7
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,693: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task common.tasks.add[68cec14f-acdc-4b10-b64b-5d6418285358] succeeded in 0.002979334007250145s: 14
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,694: INFO/MainProcess] Task common.tasks.add[106cf123-274d-41cc-a9af-a19ef84f23d0] received
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,696: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] common.tasks.add[106cf123-274d-41cc-a9af-a19ef84f23d0]: prev_result=[10, 12, 14] x=8 y=8
[2024-05-19 05:45:33,697: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] Task common.tasks.add[106cf123-274d-41cc-a9af-a19ef84f23d0] succeeded in 0.0011271659896010533s: 16

